# IntelliJIDEA high CPU Usage (over 300%)

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, cpu-usage

Please help me with my issue. I have a MacBook Pro 2011 8GB core i5, always when I'am launch IDE I hear sounds like a "Shuttle" started :( In "system monitor" I see - this result:

[image: IntelliJIDEA start]

Please help! I love this IDE. This problem occurs when I launch IDE, and when I work with several files.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems